# How to use pandas dataframe to plot point and figure chart

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, mplfinance

I am using Pandas dataframe to manipulate a financial time series consists of closing prices and time.  I would like to display the results in Point and Figure chart of Xs and Os. However, I can't find any visualization package in Python to do so.

Does anyone have experience in plotting Point and Figure charts with Python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check my answer below, otherwise, could be more clear on what you mean by point and figure charts?

Answer (score 2):

I am quite late to the party but there is a package called mplfinance.

```
pip install --upgrade mplfinance
import mplfinance as mpf
#df is the dataframe
mpf.plot(df,type='pnf')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has pandas.DataFrame.plot that enables to plot your dataframe. 
You can find the documentation here:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

The pandas doc provides an excellent tutorial on visualization of pandas dataframe and series in this link:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I have visited both sites but can't find anything "convenient" to plot Point and Figure given a pandas dataframe consisting financial time series data.

Comment: @Rolloticker can you link to an image give an example of the graph you are trying to draw?

Comment: Hi MedAli, an example image [link](http://d.stockcharts.com/school/data/media/chart_school/what_are_charts/chart-6-pnf.gif)